# MS Access: How to group by first column- summing some columns while keeping others the same

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have Data that looks like:

```
ID  |   Year    |   State   |   Cost
----+-----------+-----------+-----------
1   |   2012    |   CA      |   10
2   |   2009    |   FL      |   90  
3   |   2005    |   MA      |   50
2   |   2009    |   FL      |   75
1   |   2012    |   CA      |   110
```

I need it to look like:

```
ID  |   Year    |   State   |   Cost
----+-----------+-----------+-----------
1   |   2012    |   CA      |   120
2   |   2009    |   FL      |   165  
3   |   2005    |   MA      |   50
```

So I need the year to remain the same, the state to remain the same, but the cost to be summed for each ID.

I know how to do the summing, but I don't know how to make the year and state stay the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a `GROUP BY` or `TOTALS` Query. Something like,

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    [Year], 
    State, 
    Sum(Cost) As TotalCost
FROM 
    yourTable
GROUP BY
    ID,
    [Year],
    State;
```

A `Group By` clause GROUPS the records based on the common information. The `Sum` adds up the column specified to give you the right information.

Comment: Paul, you forgot the `Group By`.

Comment: @PaulFrancis what if i have like 60 columns, half of which I want to sum, half of which I want to leave alone. Would I have to write each one of them out like that? Or is there a faster way? Also, why are there square brackets only around some column names?

Comment: You Group the columns that you need - Yes. If the other columns does not come into calculation, then you should not add them to your query. If you did, the data will not be accurate or even right. However, if you just want to display but not sum would be a lot tricky. Regarding the square brackets, `Year` is a Keyword in Access. So using it as such will cause problems.

Comment: Use the GUI designer. Pull in the table, double-click the header of the table to use all fields, remove those not wanted. Then press the sigma sign, all fields will change to Group By. Change field Cost and other fields to Sum. Save.